# React Firebase login, show white screen instead of HomePage

Tags: reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication

I was developing an React App with authenticated with firebase, and use Redux.

My problems comes after register in the App when yo try to login, the 'section' tag desapear.

I try on other way, but stay logging until infinate of times.

The code of my firebase file is the followiing:

authActions.tsx

```
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk';

import { SignUpData, AuthAction, SET_USER, User, SET_LOADING, SIGN_OUT, SignInData, SET_ERROR, NEED_VERIFICATION, SET_SUCCESS } from '../types';
import { RootState } from '..';
import firebase from '../../firebase/config';




// Create user
export const signup = (data: SignUpData, onError: () => void): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, AuthAction> => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const res = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);
      if(res.user) {
        const userData: User = {
          email: data.email,
          firstName: data.firstName,
          id: res.user.uid,
          createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        };
        await firebase.firestore().collection('/users').doc(res.user.uid).set(userData);
        await res.user.sendEmailVerification();
        dispatch({
          type: NEED_VERIFICATION
        });
        dispatch({
          type: SET_USER,
          payload: userData
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {

      if(err instanceof Error){
      onError();
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERROR,
        payload: err.message
      });  
      }
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}

// Get user by id
export const getUserById = (id: string): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, AuthAction> => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const user = await firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(id).get();
      if(user.exists) {
        const userData = user.data() as User;
        dispatch({
          type: SET_USER,
          payload: userData
        });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}

// Set loading
export const setLoading = (value: boolean): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, AuthAction> => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_LOADING,
      payload: value
    });
  }
}

// Log in
export const signin = (data: SignInData, onError: () => void): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, AuthAction> => {

//const history =  useHistory();


  /*TODO: 
  Mandar el useHistory desde el Screen que invoca cada funcion.
  */
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)
    } catch (err) {
      if(err instanceof Error){
        onError();
        dispatch(setError(err.message));
      }
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
}

// Log out
export const signout = (): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, AuthAction> => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      dispatch(setLoading(true));
      await firebase.auth().signOut();
      dispatch({
        type: SIGN_OUT
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    }
  }
}

// Set error
export const setError = (msg: string): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, AuthAction> => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_ERROR,
      payload: msg
    });
  }
}

// Set need verification
export const setNeedVerification = (): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, AuthAction> => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: NEED_VERIFICATION
    });
  }
}

// Set success
export const setSuccess = (msg: string): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, AuthAction> => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_SUCCESS,
      payload: msg
    });
  }
}

// Send password reset email
export const sendPasswordResetEmail = (email: string, successMsg: string): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, AuthAction> => {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      await firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
      dispatch(setSuccess(successMsg));
    } catch (err) {
      if(err instanceof Error){
          dispatch(setError(err.message));
      }
      console.log(err);
    
    }
  }
}
```

The code of my SignIn Screen is the next:`

SignIn.tsx

```
import React, { FC, useState, FormEvent, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import Input from "../UI/Input";
import Button from "../UI/Button";
import Message from "../UI/Message";
import { signin, setError } from "../../store/actions/authActions";
import { RootState } from "../../store";

/* TODO: Implementar las rutas entre componentes y pages. */

const SignIn: React.FC = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();
  const { error } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (error) {
        dispatch(setError(""));
      }
    };
  }, [error, dispatch]);

  const submitHandler = (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (error) {
      dispatch(setError(""));
    }
    setLoading(true);
    /*
    Si lo pongo como abajo, carga una pagina en blanco y desaparece el section
    Si lo pongo asi: 
    dispatch(signin({ email, password }, () => {
      setLoading(false);
      dispatch(history.push("../pages/Homepage.tsx"));
    })
Se queda cargando tras intentar invocar al signin()

*/
    dispatch(signin({ email, password }, () => setLoading(false)));
    history.push("../pages/Homepage.tsx");
  };
  return (
    <section className="section">
      <div className="container">
        <h2 className="has-text-centered is-size-2 mb-3">Sign In</h2>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
          {error && <Message type="danger" msg={error} />}
          <Input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.currentTarget.value)}
            placeholder="Email address"
            label="Email address"
          />
          <Input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.currentTarget.value)}
            placeholder="Password"
            label="Password"
          />
          <p>
            <Link to="/forgot-password">Forgot password ?</Link>
          </p>
          <p>
            <Link to="/signup">Create Account</Link>
          </p>
          <Button
            text={loading ? "Loading..." : "Sign In"}
            className="is-primary is-fullwidth mt-5"
            disabled={loading}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

Finally the main code of my App is this:

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

import Header from "./components/sections/Header";
import SignUp from "./components/pages/SignUp";
import SignIn from "./components/pages/SignIn";
import ForgotPassword from "./components/pages/ForgotPassword";
import Homepage from "./components/pages/Homepage";
import Dashboard from "./components/pages/Dashboard";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/auth/PrivateRoute";
import PublicRoute from "./components/auth/PublicRoute";
import Loader from "./components/UI/Loader";
import firebase from "./firebase/config";
import {
  getUserById,
  setLoading,
  setNeedVerification,
} from "./store/actions/authActions";
import { RootState } from "./store";

const App: FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { loading } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);

  // Check if user exists
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true));
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        dispatch(setLoading(true));
        await dispatch(getUserById(user.uid));
        if (!user.emailVerified) {
          dispatch(setNeedVerification());
        }
      }
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [dispatch]);

  if (loading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <PublicRoute path="/homepage" component={Homepage} exact />
        <PublicRoute path="/signup" component={SignUp} exact />
        <PublicRoute path="/signin" component={SignIn} exact />
        <PublicRoute path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} exact />
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} exact />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I add a screenshot of the app after logging in it.

[image]

I hope you can guess where the errors comes, and if like this, take thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a full reproducible example, it would be hard to ascertain the error cause as the flow of authentication would radically change.

Meanwhile, the error should be caused by the fact that the loading state is globally shared between the `SignIn` and main `App` components which would then be toggled on and off by these (and any other subscribing component) upon some conditions assertions which should be related to authentication in your case.

To have a correct authentication flow, you should encapsulate both authentication validation and conditional page routing to the same component being the `App` in this case:

```
  // App.tsx
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setLoading(true));
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        await dispatch(getUserById(user.uid));
        if (user.emailVerified) {
          history.push('/homepage');
        }  else {
          dispatch(setNeedVerification());
        }
      }
      dispatch(setLoading(false));
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  });
```

The form `submitHandler` action creator would then be updated accordingly:

```
  const submitHandler = (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (error) {
      dispatch(setError(""));
    }
    setLoading(true);
    dispatch(signin({ email, password }, () => setLoading(false)));
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! I get I try to your answer. Although after implementing, I get the following error:n Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>

Comment: This should not be related to the original issue. Could you try posting another thread focusing on this issue with the relevant sources (there is no wrapped with `withRouter` components in the code snippet).